# Batch update counts on a table based on a join table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains the count of products by region

```
Products
-id
-name

Regions
-id
-product_count

Inventory
-id
-product_id
-region_id
```

I want to update the Regions table with the count of product_id + region_id in the Inventory table.

This would give me all the products for a single region:

```
select COUNT(*) as product_count
from inventory
where region_id=1
```

But I need to update the Regions.product_count column for all products and regions.

How can I perform this batch update?

```
Update regions
  set product_count = ??
from Regions
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregation to retrieve counts for every region. Then use a `JOIN` operation inside the `UPDATE` statement to associate your counts to your "*regions*" table, and update the value of "*regions.product_count*" accordingly.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT region_id, COUNT(*) AS num_products
    FROM inventory
    GROUP BY region_id 
)
UPDATE regions
SET product_count = cte.num_products
FROM cte
WHERE regions.region_id = cte.region_id
```

Comment: when life gives you a lemon.... thanks!